# How can I read a file, extract fields and use them in a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a script that I use to create config files for IP phones that I install.  Right now I hand input the extension number and the secret for the phone and then the MAC address so the output file can be created properly.  this works out fine.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo "Enter the Extension #:"
    read extension
    echo "Enter the phone MAC Address:
    read mac
    echo " Extension Password:"
    read password
    cat >/tftpboot/$mac.cfg << EOF
    #!version:1.0.0.1
    account.1.label = $extension
    account.1.display_name = $extension
    account.1.auth_name = $extension
    account.1.user_name = $extension
    account.1.password =  $password
    account.1.sip_server.1.address =  10.1.10.250
    account.1.sip_server.1.port = 5060
    account.1.voice_mail_number= *97
    account.1.subscribe_mwi = 1
    local_time.time_zone = -4
    local_time.ntp_server1 = 10.1.10.250
    network.qos.rtptos = 46
    network.qos.signaltos = 46
    network.port.max_rtpport = 20000
    network.port.min_rtpport = 10000
    EOF
    echo " All Done!"
```

I will have a file that will have all the extensions with the secrets on the server that this script is running on.  Here is a sample of the file:

```
[100]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
secret=60770f7d87b72dd451dbfd2dd8143b2b
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
context=from-internal
host=dynamic
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=pai
type=friend
nat=yes
port=5060
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=60
transport=udp
encryption=no
callgroup=
pickupgroup=
dial=SIP/100
mailbox=100@default
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
callerid=100 <100>
callcounter=yes
faxdetect=no
cc_monitor_policy=generic

[101]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
secret=7c2166c495ccbb637ae43e63c47de435
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
context=from-internal
host=dynamic
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=pai
type=friend
nat=yes
port=5060
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=60
transport=udp
encryption=no
callgroup=
pickupgroup=
dial=SIP/101
mailbox=101@default
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
callerid=101 <101>
callcounter=yes
faxdetect=no
cc_monitor_policy=generic
```

The extension number is in the brackets [100] and the secret is two lines below.  There could be 100 extensions or more.  Ideally I would like to run th escript and scan in the MAC address with a barcode scanner for each phone.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The following awk will read *file* and output the extension number and the secret

```
awk  '{if ($0 ~ "\[[[:digit:]]\]") {gsub("\\[|\\]","");ext=$0} else if ($0 ~ "secret.*") {gsub("secret=","");print ext " " $1}}' file 2>/dev/null
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming that it does not matter which phone (MAC) will be assigned the extension and secret, 
you can use it in a `while` loop and assign the output to two different variables. If you want to read the MAC for each pair manually, i.e., pause execution and input MAC, then you will have to do that inside the `while` loop. You cannot just read from `STDIN` (`fd0`) , however, since `STDIN` is alread reading the output of `awk`. Hence, a `read` from fd0 would just read the next token from `awk`'s output. This can be fixed by using a different file descriptor (`fd3` in this example) which first has to be pointed to STDIN. This is what the `exec` does. Now you can `read` from `fd3` inside the `while` loop and the execution will stop until input is available.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<&0 # new file descriptor to read from stdin

file="$1"

while read -r extension password;do
    echo -n "Input MAC address for extension ${extension}: "
    read -u 3 mac # read from fd3 to allow for manual input
    cat > "./${mac}.cfg" << EOF
#!version:1.0.0.1
account.1.label = $extension
account.1.display_name = $extension
account.1.auth_name = $extension
account.1.user_name = $extension
account.1.password =  $password
account.1.sip_server.1.address =  10.1.10.250
account.1.sip_server.1.port = 5060
account.1.voice_mail_number= *97
account.1.subscribe_mwi = 1
local_time.time_zone = -4
local_time.ntp_server1 = 10.1.10.250
network.qos.rtptos = 46
network.qos.signaltos = 46
network.port.max_rtpport = 20000
network.port.min_rtpport = 10000
EOF
# ^ no leading whitespace before EOF allowed
done < <(awk  '{if ($0 ~ "\[[[:digit:]]\]") {gsub("\\[|\\]","");ext=$0} else if ($0 ~ "secret.*") {gsub("secret=","");print ext " " $1}}' "${file}" 2>/dev/null )

exec 3<&- # close file descriptor
```

The script expects the filename with the extension and secret as its first parameter. You should take measures in case you accidentally hit `Enter` and then skip an extension/secret pair while inputting the MAC address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I ran the first command on my file and I got the secrets but no extensions .

Comment: @EdLentz Which distribution are you using? What is the output of `awk --version`? The command works with my distro (Ubuntu Mate) and GNU awk 4.1.3.

Comment: I was trying to develop this on a raspberry Pi with Raspian Jesse.  The version command doesn't work.  I moved over to a Centos 6 system I am also using and the awk works.  Version 3.1.7  I get the extension and the secret.  Now to integrate the While into my script.  Thanks

Comment: Running the while within my script it prints the extension and the secret.  Ideally I would like it to step from one ext/secret pair to the next with a manual input of the Mac address. then move on to the next pair until all are done.

Comment: Does your updated script work on your system?  When I change "file" in the awk command to the file that has the ext and secret info I get an error "bad substitution"  Is that where my file location is supposed to be for that file?

Comment: @EdLentz You are supposed to pass the filename as parameter to the script. Save the script, e.g., as `phone_conf.sh` and make it executable. Then you can call it like `./phone_conf.sh filename`. The `${file}` is now a variable. Alternatively, you will have to substitute the entire `${file}` with the filename.

Comment: Figured it out and created some files !!  One last thing.  Can the extension number show up in the "Enter Mac Address" print line?  Just so I can keep track of which one is being created?

Comment: Figured that out as well.  Thank you so much for your help!  I think that will do me just fine.

Comment: @EdLentz Please upvote and accept my answer if it works.